# Delimit multiple names that are display like lastname, firstname

Tags: users, names

I wonder what would be the best way to delimit multiple names in a user management web app that is completely in English.

I guess normally one would separate by commas or semicolons but in this scenario I have to use the format [lastname, firstname], which doesn't look good.

```
Pinkman, Jesse; White, Walter; Ehrmantraut, Mike
```

Any ideas on how to display multiple names that are formated [lastname, firstname]?

Comment: Are you *sure* they're *always* lastname,firstname? Becaase that's a big assumption. See: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: I was quite sure before I read the article, but now I feel kinda different. Indeed the database is built with first_name, last_name, but I'm afraid I can't change that. Thanks for the good read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Web app, you can use the full set of UX elements, not only the usual text symbols.

Most email programs draw a shaded box around a person's complete name to represent the name as a logical unit. Then you only need white space between these boxes.

[image: Two names in shaded boxes]

If for some reason you can/want to only use a simple text field, there are a range of UTF-8 symbols, emojis and even ASCII symbols which can visually separate the name pairs.

```
Examples: | / -- []
```

Comment: The one draw back is the affordance of looking like buttons or tags, but yes, I agree this problem shouldn't be solved by ASCII characters when CSS is on the table